# I have Crystal report and need to use results from parameter based on one table to run a parameter on another table

Tags: crystal-reports

My SQL Table contains RmaNumber, RmaLineNumber and Warehouse, and then a whel lot of other details. 
We want to filter (using a parameter) on warehouse to produce a list of RMANumbers and RMALinenumbers to choose from. The problem is that when I include the RmaLineNumbers it makes the dataset to large to display in Crystal Reports.
So I tried splittin the data into 2 tables - the first table contains the Warehouse and RMANumber. The second table contains the RmaNumber and RmaLine Number. The idea is that I put a parameter on the first table to select the warehouse and it returns a list of RMANumbers (a manageable size data set)Then the user will select which RMANumbers they want and from that list I want to  filter (parameter) From the second table to see the line numbers (a smaller dataset) then the report will display the details based on the line number chosen.  Is what I am trying to do possible in Crystal? is there another way around the issue of the dataset being to large?

Comment: you can achieve it by using cascading parameter

Comment: A cascading parameter does not work when I am want to create a parameter based on the results of another parameter that ran on a different table : table A data is filterd according to Parameter A, and a set of data is chosen,  am then wanting to select data from Table B based on the data chosen from Parameter A.... I dont know if i am explaining this clearly...

Comment: which table is in the crystal report? the 1st or the 2nd table?

Comment: Both tables are in the report :)